# Redirect After Proxy Apache2

Tags: apache, server, proxy, webserver

I have an application that runs on *https://ip:8443*. I have an Apache2 proxy server that stands in front of this application with the following config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain
        ServerAlias mydomain
        Redirect permanent / https://mydomain/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ServerName mydomain
        ServerAlias mydomain
        ProxyPass / https://ip:8443/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://ip:8443/
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I hit *https://mydomain* on the browser it works fine and shows *https://ip:8443* content.

Now I want when someone visits *https://mydomain* to be redirected to another URL *https://mydomain/subfolder* which shows *https://ip:8443/subfolder*.

I searched for a week and tried a lot of solutions here but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me.

I added the following lines to `<VirtualHost *:443>`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ...
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
        RewriteRule (.*) https://mydomain/subfolder/ [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```